# The default path to external SD in Genymotion

Tags: android

I am using GenyMotion emulators ([link](http://www.genymotion.com)).
My App needs to download and save some files in SD card. This line of code returns `/storage/emulated/0/` as external storage path:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Problem is that `/storage/emulated/0/` directory  is not writable and I can not save downloaded file in this folder. When I look in DDMS file explorer view, there is no `0` folder in `/storage/emulated/` path and I am not authorized to create a directory or put a file here manually.

There is directory in `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/` that seems to be SD card (it contains all default android directories and is writable) but is not returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` method.

Why this directory is write protected?
And where is exact SD card storage?

Answer (score 4):

Wasn't under /mnt/sdcard for me. Found it in /mnt/shell/emulated

Comment: Thank you! In the code, getAbsolutePath() returns /storage/emulated/0/..., and I could not find it with the File Explorer of ADM.  Thanks to your tip, I see it in mnt/shell/emulated/0/...  I believe your answer is the right one.

Answer (score -1):

look in `/mnt/sdcard` folder. worked for my audio recording app. I was able to save my recordings in sdcard successfully.Use  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` to get the path for sd card.

Comment: I'm also using  GenyMotion emulator.

Comment: well, hooray for hardcoded info ... NOT. What do you think 'Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()'. The question was, why the framework returned a wrong or unusable info where it usually does not fail on real devices.